# What's the idiomatic way to temporarily change the destination of a Laravel Notification?

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have a Notification that is typically sent to the user's stored mobile number. That's easy.

But occasionally, the user can direct us to send it to a number they don't want us to store. The UI is clear (in this rarer case) that they're entrusting us with this number just to deliver this notification.

Is there a reasonable place I can store this one-off destination that *isn't* on the model?  If I store it in a non-persisting attribute of the model, it's gone by the time the asynchronous job runs.  If I store it in the Notification object (e.g., passed in through the constructor), it doesn't matter because the model's `routeNotificationFor*()` methods can't see that.